# project is crashing in android

Tags: java, android

I want to make an application which will check abusive words in a string entered by user and if there is no abusive words then it will post to other applications and if the string entred by user  contains abusive words then a pop will be generated .

Here is my code in normal java abusive word checking is working good but in android it is just crashing.

I am giving error report of logcat

```
  06-26 14:44:27.333: W/System.err(338):    at                                             android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    06-26 14:44:27.343: W/System.err(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-26 14:44:27.343: W/System.err(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    06-26 14:44:27.353: W/System.err(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    06-26 14:44:27.353: W/System.err(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    06-26 14:44:27.363: W/System.err(338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-26 14:44:27.373: D/AndroidRuntime(338): Shutting down VM
    06-26 14:44:27.373: W/dalvikvm(338): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.vssgatekeeper.Main$1.onClick(Main.java:62)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
    06-26 14:44:27.383: E/AndroidRuntime(338):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    06-26 14:44:31.723: I/Process(338): Sending signal. PID: 338 SIG: 9
    06-26 14:51:24.365: D/dalvikvm(376): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 50K, 53% free 2552K/5379K, external 716K/1038K, paused 100ms
```

With the following code:

```
package com.vssgatekeeper;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.vssgatekeeper.library.DatabaseHandler;
import com.vssgatekeeper.library.UserFunctions;

public class Main extends Activity
{
    Button btnLogout, share;
    Button changepas;
    EditText post;

    /**
    * Called when the activity is first created.
    */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        changepas = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btchangepass);
        btnLogout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logout);
        share = (Button) findViewById(R.id.share);
        post = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.comment);
        String comment=post.getText().toString();

        share.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                BufferedReader reader = null;
                try
                {
                    reader = new BufferedReader(new                      FileReader(new      File("C:\\Users\\Prateek\\Desktop\\abusivewords.txt")));
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String inputLine = null;
                HashSet dictionary = new HashSet();

                try
                {
                    while((inputLine = reader.readLine()) != null)
                    {
                        String[] words = inputLine.split("\\n+");

                        if(inputLine.equals("")) continue;

                        for(String word: words)
                        {
                            word = word.replace(".", "");
                            word = word.replace(",", "");

                            dictionary.add(word);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                try
                {
                    reader.close();
                }
                catch (IOException e)
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String search[] = null;

                int exit=0;
                boolean found=false;
                do
                {
                    search=post.getText().toString().split(" ");
                    for(String srch : search)
                    {
                        if(dictionary.contains(srch))
                        {
                            found = true;
                        }
                    }
                    if(!found)
                    {
                        Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
                        sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, post.getText().toString().concat("\n").concat("@ Posted By GateKeeper"));
                        sendIntent.setType("text/plain");

                        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, post.getText().toString().concat("\n").concat("@  Posted By GateKeeper")));
                    }
                    search = null;
                }while(exit==0);
            }
        });

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        /**
        * Hashmap to load data from the Sqlite database
        **/
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        user = db.getUserDetails();

        /**
        * Change Password Activity Started
        **/
        changepas.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent chgpass = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                ChangePassword.class);

                startActivity(chgpass);
            }
        });

        /**
        * Logout from the User Panel which clears the data in Sqlite database
        **/
        btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                UserFunctions logout = new UserFunctions();
                logout.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                Intent login = new                                                  Intent(getApplicationContext(),          Login.class);
                login.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(login);
                finish();
            }
        });
        /**
        * Sets user first name and last name in text view.
        **/
        final TextView login = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textwelcome);
        login.setText("Welcome  " + user.get("fname"));
        final TextView lname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lname);
        lname.setText(user.get("lname"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Your android device doesn't have a `C:` path.

Comment: want a sloution to this proble,

Comment: Change the file path to a file that exists on your device.

Answer (score 0):

Its like laalto said. 
The error roots from here:

> reader = new BufferedReader(new                      FileReader(new      File("C:\Users\Prateek\Desktop\abusivewords.txt")));

The "abusivewords.txt" should exist within your project, not inside the folder of your desktop

Best solution for that is place "abusivewords.txt" inside your assets folder of your project and call it in your code like this:

> AssetManager mngr = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
>       InputStream is = mngr.open("textdb.txt");

Answer (score 0):

put your `abusivewords.txt` file in sdcard and change your path from `"C:\\Users\\Prateek\\Desktop\\abusivewords.txt")` to sdcard

You can get the path of sdcard from this code:

```
File sdCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File myDir = new File(sdCardRoot, "Your file name");
```

You will get your directory path here myDir

Comment: But how/why will a random user put the file in his sd card. Won't it be better for him to store it in assets.

Answer (score 0):

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\Users\\Prateek\\Desktop\\abusivewords.txt")));
```

Your android device cannot read files stored in the C Drive of your computer. You'll need to store the file locally, i.e. within your application. So, put the file within the assets folder of your application.

You'll then be able to read the file :

```
    StringBuilder buf=new StringBuilder();
    InputStream json=getAssets().open("abusivewords.txt");
    BufferedReader in=
        new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(json, "UTF-8"));
    String str;

    while ((str=in.readLine()) != null) {
      buf.append(str);
    }

    in.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

As there is no C: drive or no such path like the one you have specified on a mobile, the "new File" doesn't exist, you can replace that part by the path of `externalStorageDirectory` like:

```
//associated with the path   
 File externalStorageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
 reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(externalStorageDir, "abusivewords.txt")));
```

For more info:
[Storage Options - Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
and [Saving files](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html)

Answer (score 0):

place abusivewords.txt into assets project folder and replace

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new                      FileReader(new      File("C:\\Users\\Prateek\\Desktop\\abusivewords.txt")));
```

by

```
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Main.this.getAssets().open("abusivewords.txt"))
```